# How to install the Genie Package in julia 1.6.2?

Tags: centos, julia, genie.jl

I am trying to install Genie Package on Julia 1.6.2 on CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core).

But, getting the following error.  Please guide me in resolving the Genie installation issue!

logs:

```
    [root@srvr0 ~]# julia
                   _
       _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
      (_)     | (_) (_)    |
       _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
      | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
      | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.6.2 (2021-07-14)
     _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
    |__/                   |
    
    julia> versioninfo()
    Julia Version 1.6.2
    Commit 1b93d53fc4 (2021-07-14 15:36 UTC)
    Platform Info:
      OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
      CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       M 620  @ 2.67GHz
      WORD_SIZE: 64
      LIBM: libopenlibm
      LLVM: libLLVM-11.0.1 (ORCJIT, westmere)
    Environment:
      JULIA_DEPOT_PATH = /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6
      JULIA_PROJECT = /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6
      JULIA_LOAD_PATH = /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6
      JULIA_PKG_DEVDIR = /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6
      JULIA_HOME = /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2
      JULIA_HISTORY = /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/logs/repl_history.jl
    
julia> using Pkg

julia> import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()
Precompiling project...
  ✗ MbedTLS
  ✗ Nettle_jll
  ✗ XML2_jll
  ✗ HTTP
  ✗ Nettle
  ✗ EzXML
  ✗ UrlDownload
  ✗ VersionCheck
  ✗ Genie
  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 89 seconds (47 already precompiled)

ERROR: The following 3 direct dependencies failed to precompile:

MbedTLS [739be429-bea8-5141-9913-cc70e7f3736d]

Failed to precompile MbedTLS [739be429-bea8-5141-9913-cc70e7f3736d] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/MbedTLS/jl_Xqj7WF.
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package MbedTLS_jll [c8ffd9c3-330d-5841-b78e-0817d7145fa1] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.

Stacktrace:
 [1] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1012
 [2] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:936
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:923
 [4] include
   @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
 [5] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
 [6] top-level scope
   @ none:1
 [7] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [8] eval(x::Expr)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [9] top-level scope
   @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/MbedTLS/4YY6E/src/MbedTLS.jl:1

HTTP [cd3eb016-35fb-5094-929b-558a96fad6f3]

Failed to precompile HTTP [cd3eb016-35fb-5094-929b-558a96fad6f3] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/HTTP/jl_Yyye6x.
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package MbedTLS_jll [c8ffd9c3-330d-5841-b78e-0817d7145fa1] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.

Stacktrace:
 [1] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1012
 [2] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:936
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:923
 [4] include
   @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
 [5] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
 [6] top-level scope
   @ none:1
 [7] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [8] eval(x::Expr)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [9] top-level scope
   @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/MbedTLS/4YY6E/src/MbedTLS.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile MbedTLS [739be429-bea8-5141-9913-cc70e7f3736d] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/MbedTLS/jl_gvFbMy.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IOContext{Base.PipeEndpoint}, internal_stdout::IOContext{IOStream}, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1385
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1329
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1043
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:936
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:923
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:386
  [8] include(x::String)
    @ HTTP /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/HTTP.jl:1
  [9] top-level scope
    @ /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/HTTP.jl:33
 [10] include
    @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
 [11] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [13] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [14] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [15] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/IOExtras.jl:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/HTTP.jl:1


Genie [c43c736e-a2d1-11e8-161f-af95117fbd1e]

Failed to precompile Genie [c43c736e-a2d1-11e8-161f-af95117fbd1e] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/Genie/jl_vquqzS.
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package MbedTLS_jll [c8ffd9c3-330d-5841-b78e-0817d7145fa1] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.

Stacktrace:
 [1] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1012
 [2] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:936
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:923
 [4] include
   @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
 [5] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
 [6] top-level scope
   @ none:1
 [7] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [8] eval(x::Expr)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [9] top-level scope
   @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/MbedTLS/4YY6E/src/MbedTLS.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile MbedTLS [739be429-bea8-5141-9913-cc70e7f3736d] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/MbedTLS/jl_InozY8.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IOContext{Base.PipeEndpoint}, internal_stdout::IOContext{IOStream}, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1385
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1329
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1043
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:936
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:923
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:386
  [8] include(x::String)
    @ HTTP /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/HTTP.jl:1
  [9] top-level scope
    @ /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/HTTP.jl:33
 [10] include
    @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
 [11] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [13] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [14] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [15] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/IOExtras.jl:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/HTTP/aTjcj/src/HTTP.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile HTTP [cd3eb016-35fb-5094-929b-558a96fad6f3] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/HTTP/jl_A9Y88m.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IOContext{Base.PipeEndpoint}, internal_stdout::IOContext{IOStream}, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1385
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1329
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1043
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:936
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:923
  [7] include
    @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
  [8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
  [9] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [10] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [11] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/UrlDownload/30tLC/src/UrlDownload.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile UrlDownload [856ac37a-3032-4c1c-9122-f86d88358c8b] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/UrlDownload/jl_zopYYu.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IOContext{Base.PipeEndpoint}, internal_stdout::IOContext{IOStream}, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1385
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1329
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1043
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:936
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:923
  [7] include
    @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
  [8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
  [9] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [10] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [11] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/VersionCheck/IzZOn/src/VersionCheck.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile VersionCheck [a637dc6b-bca1-447e-a4fa-35264c9d0580] to /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/compiled/v1.6/VersionCheck/jl_gmYXFo.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IOContext{Base.PipeEndpoint}, internal_stdout::IOContext{IOStream}, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1385
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1329
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1043
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:936
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:923
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:386
  [8] include(x::String)
    @ Genie /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/Genie/Qtv4L/src/Genie.jl:4
  [9] top-level scope
    @ /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/Genie/Qtv4L/src/Genie.jl:12
 [10] include
    @ ./Base.jl:386 [inlined]
 [11] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1235
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [13] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [14] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:446
 [15] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/Genie/Qtv4L/src/Configuration.jl:1
in expression starting at /opt/julia/julia-1.6.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/packages/Genie/Qtv4L/src/Genie.jl:1

Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(msg::String)
   @ Pkg.Types /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/Types.jl:55
 [2] precompile(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context; internal_call::Bool, strict::Bool, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
   @ Pkg.API /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/API.jl:1265
 [3] precompile
   @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/API.jl:921 [inlined]
 [4] #precompile#196
   @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/API.jl:919 [inlined]
 [5] precompile()
   @ Pkg.API /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/API.jl:919
 [6] top-level scope
   @ REPL[16]:1

julia>
```

Comment: Have you tried running `Pkg.instantiate()`?

Comment: `Pkg.build()` could also help

Comment: Note that the problems here are also likely related to the suboptimal `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` choice that's mentioned in [the answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70413643/8127).

Comment: In general there are no known issues with Genie on CentOS and Julia 1.6 so it looks like the issue lies with the MbetTLS package. Can you try adding that separately via `pkd> add MbedTLS` and see how that works?

Answer (score 0):

First follow what instructions tell your to do

```
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.instantiate()
```

If that doesn't resolve the error add MbedTLS. You should install

```
julia> ]
pkg> add MbedTLS
pkg> add Genie#master
```